# View shows sub view outside of it in swift

Tags: ios, swift, view

in swift when you define a view with a frame and insert a subview into it (for example a label) the subview will be shown even if it is outside the view's frame. How can I make sure that the view will show only the subviews that are in the frame? (The reason I want that is that I want to animate a view with subviews and make it disappear but the subview stays)

Comment: It is always to scroll through the docs or UIView at least once to at least get an idea for what it is possible out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `clipsToBounds = true`. The default value is `false` which means the subviews are not clipped. Note that there is a small performance penalty to doing this as it requires extra compositing.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds):

> Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds
> of the receiver. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond
> the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value
> is false.

Answer (score 0):

You should to set `clipToBounds` to true. That property determines whether subviews are confined to the bounds of the view.